# set position, top and left for a draggable object

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a draggable object set to position:relative but I need to change it from relative to absolute  only when I drag it and I want the object to stay in its initial space. 
I tried to set "drag" in this way:

```
$('obj').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: true,
    drag: function () {
        var posizione = $(this).position();
        var posizione_x = posizione.left;
        var posizione_y = posizione.top;
        $(this).css({
            "left": posizione_x,
            "top": posizione_y,
            "position": "absolute"
        });
    },
    stop: function () {
        $(this).css("position", "relative");
    }
})
```

or in this way:

```
$('obj').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: true,
    drag: function () {
        var posizione_x = $(this).offsetLeft;
        var posizione_y = $(this).offsetTop;
        $(this).css({
            "left": posizione_x,
            "top": posizione_y,
            "position": "absolute"
        });
    },
    stop: function () {
        $(this).css("position", "relative");
    }
})
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: .offset().left and -offset().top don't work too.

Comment: doesn't work = my object has absolute position but has top:0 and left:0

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `.offset().left` and `.offset().top`

Could you detail "does not work" (error in the console? what happend? how is positionned the element?)

And `$('obj')` target a `<obj>` tag, are you certain you element is well targeted?

Maybe you try to do something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleKatarn/awjh79uw/1/